# Get Checkboxlist selected Item using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have selected 2 items from the `checkboxlist` with below code which I tried I am getting error as

> attributes is not defined.

Here is my code

```
var checkboxlist = document.getElementById('<%= ddlStatus.ClientID %>');
        var checkOptions =   checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var listSelected = checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('span');

        for(i = 0; i < checkOptions.length; i++)
        {
            if(checkOptions[i].checked)
            {
                alert(listSelected[i].attributes["STATUS"].value);
            }
        }
```

kindly let me know how to get the selected value

**UPDATE**

Fiddle of the checkboxlist with 2 items selected

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg8w2u7d/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, in your JSFiddle you're checkbox titles are in `label` not `span` so change this line:

```
var listSelected = checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

to:

```
var listSelected = checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('label');
```

apart from that, you don't have an attribute called `"STATUS"` on those labels, I've updated your fiddle - see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lg8w2u7d/2/

UPDATE

final code that gets last selected value, with compatibility to IE8

```
 var checkboxlist = document.getElementById('ddlStatus');
 var checkOptions =   checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var listSelected = checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('label');
 var last_val = '';
 for(i = 0; i < checkOptions.length; i++)
        {
            if(checkOptions[i].checked)
            {
                last_val = listSelected[i].textContent || listSelected[i].innerText; // so it works in IE8 and lower
            }
        }
 alert(last_val);
```

Comment: yes, i dont have status. so how to set the values in the variable which is selected from the list ?

Comment: you mean alert the value of the selected checkbox? like this:  `alert(checkOptions[i].value);` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg8w2u7d/5/

Comment: yes, exactly this one. One more thing here, how to set the last selected value ??

Comment: get the last selected value into a variable? you can store it into a variable, and assign value inside the loop, it will leave you with the last one - https://jsfiddle.net/Lg8w2u7d/6/ . you can also store to array and then take maximum, it depends on your need

Comment: I am getting value as 20, but in my list the `agreement` is getting selected. Here is my full code in the fiddle **Updated fiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/1mmdgcsg/1/

Comment: Now, I got the value as `20` properly. But in list 20 is getting set, I want to set the text of 20 which is Registration

Comment: first of all - I've changed things in here: https://jsfiddle.net/1mmdgcsg/2/ had to comment out a couple of lines that gave errors due to incomplete code. (also added a button to run the code) as for getting the text of the last selected checkbox - see here: https://jsfiddle.net/1mmdgcsg/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125788/discussion-between-nad-and-jameson-the-dog).